# Conducting a Pilot Study without Large Sample

Tags: sample-size, small-sample, exploratory-data-analysis

I want to obtain preliminary evidence that some experimental manipulations I would like to use in research have a good chance of being successful (i.e., successfully manipulating the intended construct).  Thus, I would like to pilot these manipulations.

There are three such manipulations and I run my studies in a three-cubicle lab.  So, running subjects is slow.  I work in psychology where the typical effect size is small and obtaining a very large sample size to keep power high sort of defeats the purpose of these pilot studies.  I will obtain whatever sample size is necessary for high power in the actual experiments even if they are several hundred subjects.  However, I cannot do three pilots with several hundred subjects and then three main studies with also several hundred subjects.

How can I obtain preliminary evidence from pilot studies that the manipulations are likely to have construct validity without having to run huge samples?

Note that I am not interested in doing power analysis for the main studies on the basis of the pilots.  The sole interest is to validate the manipulations.

Comment: I don't understand, it looks like power analysis is exactly what you need, that is to calculate the probability of finding a statistically significant result, if it exists. Explain what "validate the manipulations" means?

Comment: No, I do not need a power analysis for the main studies.  I am NOT trying to generate an estimate of effect size or anything.  I have developed manipulations that are designed to change people's perceptions.  I simply want some indication that these manipulations are likely to achieve the intended effect (I have questions regarding perceptions that can show this, which I will not use in the original studies).  Think of it like checking basic quality of scale items before collecting lots of data to for factor structure.

Comment: You can collect a small sample and calculate the effect of the individual "manipulations" in the sample and use these in the power analysis to determine the required sample size for your main study, that is determine how big of a sample you need (in your main study) to find a significant effect, if it exists, with high enough probability. How big should your sample be in your preliminary study? Not too small. Trying to assert whether your "manipulations" are significant from a small preliminary study is almost sure to give very uncertain results.

Comment: Significance is not the only way to do this, that's why I tried referring to "preliminary" evidence and exploratory data analysis (in the tag).  In the pilot studies, I will not use the main DV that I will use in the actual studies; as I tried to explain before (because the DV is not suitable for validating the manipulation).  And once again, I am not interested in power analysis for the actual study (I can easily take care of that by specifying a SESOI -smallest effect size of interest).  I think we keep talking past each other, but thanks for your opinion.

Comment: There are people on this site with lots of experience analyzing data from different fields. If you could give a little more info, maybe someone can be helpful. What do you mean by 'manipulations'? What info you need for validation of them in pilot study? And, what objective for main study when you get to it? // It's like you're telling us "I have to weigh this 'object'. How would I do that?" Well, use a laboratory balance, a postal scale, a bathroom scale, ... or a highway truck scale--take your pick.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try to add more info or delete the question. I thought concepts like experiment and manipulation were very basic and shared across fields and I tried to briefly explain what the manipulations were.  Maybe I was naive.